# how to assign variable as div name in jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax

when click link i calling `ajax` method which will return data as `object`. In data which will have my group name. I am trying to `empty the group and create a new div` but i am getting error Please let me know some thing from your end :).

```
function loadData(data) {
    var view = new entryView(data);
    var groupName = data.name;
    $("#groupName").attr('id').empty();
    // error - typeerror $(...).attr(...) is undefined jquery
    alert($('#groupName').attr('id'));
}

entryView(data) {
    this.name = this.data.name
}
```

I keep getting `TypeError: $(...).attr(...) is undefined`. Can someone please tell me what the problem is? My jQuery is below. Thank you.

Comment: what browser are you using?

Comment: You're trying to call the `empty()` method on a string which is why you get the error

Comment: and is this line run alert($('#groupName').attr('id')); if you put before the error line? and what it shows in the alert?

Comment: how about trying this: 

    $("#"+groupName).attr('id','');

Comment: or $("#"+data.name).empty()

Answer (score 0):

how about trying this:

```
$("#"+groupName).attr('id','');
```

Answer (score 0):

`undefined` means it cannot find any selector that match your selected element.. It's because `groupName` is a variable and you cannot put it inside double quote, because it will change `groupName` into `String` instead of a variable.

Change your code from:

```
$("#groupName").attr('id').empty();
```

into this:

```
$("#"+groupName).attr('id','');
```

If you use jQuery version 1.6 or above, use `.prop()` like this:

```
$("#"+groupName).prop('id','');
```

Comment: document.getElementById(groupName).innerHTML = "";

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to guess what you mean without html and I guess you also have an X/Y problem

If I have to guess you want

```
$("#*+groupName).empty();
```

which will empty the container with ID equal to groupName

or just

```
$("#*+groupName).html(data.content);
```

which will replace the content

Answer (score 0):

If you are selecting an element with a specific ID, you don't need jQuery:

```
function loadData(data) {
    var view = new entryView(data); // I have no idea what this supposed to be doing.

    var groupName = data.name;
    var element = document.getElementById(groupName);
    alert(element.id);
    element.id = ""; // you can use this as a normal property, no "attr" magic
    alert(element.id);
}
```